# Combine Queries where one is recursive

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a recursive query that creates a row for each hour of the previous month as follows;

```
 WITH a AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) AS [DateTime]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dateadd(hour, 1, [DateTime])
    FROM a
    WHERE dateadd(hour, 1, [DateTime]) < EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)
    )
 SELECT 
     a.*

 FROM a

 OPTION (maxrecursion 0);
```

This produces these results;

```
 DateTime
 2020-11-01 00:00:00.000
 2020-11-01 01:00:00.000
 2020-11-01 02:00:00.000
 etc.....
```

Next I have a query that calculates the number of calls per customer, per hour, for the previous month, as a 4 week average as follows;

```
SELECT
DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0,
    DATEADD(minute, 30 - DATEPART(minute, Timestamp + '00:30:00.000'),
    Timestamp)), 0)  as RoundedToHour,
Campaign,
COUNT(*)/4 AS Average

FROM [Reporting].[dbo].[New_Five9_CallLog] WITH (NOLOCK)

WHERE DATEDIFF(mm, Timestamp, GETDATE()) = 1
AND Call_Type = 'Inbound'

GROUP BY Campaign,
    DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0,
        DATEADD(minute, 30 - DATEPART(minute, Timestamp + '00:30:00.000'),
        Timestamp)), 0)
```

This produces the following results;

```
RoundedToHour             Campaign     Average
2020-11-01 02:00:00.000   Client1      0
2020-11-01 04:00:00.000   Client2      2
etc....
```

What I am having trouble doing is combining these two. My initial thoughts were to use a CTE of the recursive query as basically a where clause in my second query, but since you have to use a WITH for CTE's, and I have to use a WITH for my recursive query, that won't directly work, because you can't have nested WITH's.

My final result I am looking for is a single query that produces the 4 week average of calls for each hour of the previous month, for each client. I am open to changing how I am doing any of this if someone has a better suggestion on how to reach my ultimate goal.

Comment: Please show us some sample data for the final result.

Comment: This is effectively a tally table. See https://sqlperformance.com/2020/12/t-sql-queries/number-series-challenge and https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/tally-tables-in-t-sql for much better solutions than recursive CTE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare a CTE in a sub-query but you *can* declare multiple CTEs together. So declare both and then `LEFT JOIN` them.

```
WITH a AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) AS [DateTime]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dateadd(hour, 1, [DateTime])
    FROM a
    WHERE dateadd(hour, 1, [DateTime]) < EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)
), b AS (
    SELECT
        DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0,
            DATEADD(minute, 30 - DATEPART(minute, Timestamp + '00:30:00.000'),
            Timestamp)), 0)  as RoundedToHour,
        Campaign,
        COUNT(*)/4 AS Average
    FROM [Reporting].[dbo].[New_Five9_CallLog] WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE DATEDIFF(mm, Timestamp, GETDATE()) = 1
    AND Call_Type = 'Inbound'
    GROUP BY Campaign,
        DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0,
            DATEADD(minute, 30 - DATEPART(minute, Timestamp + '00:30:00.000'),
            Timestamp)), 0)
)
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b on b.RoundedToHour = a.DateTime
OPTION (maxrecursion 0);
```

Comment: This not only worked perfect, but I was able to add some other data points to make it more encompassing. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: In addition to this technique, I suggest getting familiar with using `cross apply` and `outer apply` - they essentially allow you to join on sub-queries (or table valued functions) using values from the initial query.